# How to concat multiple array observables that some might not emit any stream

Tags: angular, rxjs5

Let's say I have following situation:

```
allItems$: <(TypeA | TypeB)[]>;
arr1$: TypeA[]; // [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
arr2$: TypeA[];
arr3$: TypeB[]; // [{ b:1, c: 2}, { b:3, c: 4}]
arr4$: TypeB[];
```

I would like to concat all together into one single array, but some of these streams might not emit any value, do you know which is a proper operator?

```
this.allItems$ = operator([
  arr1$,
  arr2$,
  arr3$,
  arr4$
]).pipe(
   // returned value
);
```

Desired output:

```
// [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, { b:1, c: 2}, { b:3, c: 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is **ZIP** but it will not work if one of your observable doesn't emit a value, so i suggest that you use **MERGE** and try to push the emitted value into an array each time you have it, here is a working solution for your case:

```
import { delay, last, switchMap, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { of, zip, merge } from "rxjs";


let array = [];

const sourceOne = of("Hello");
const sourceTwo = of("World!");
const sourceThree = of(); // observable that doesn't emit a value
const sourceFour = of("World!");

const example = merge(
 sourceOne,
 sourceTwo.pipe(delay(1000)),
 sourceThree.pipe(delay(2000)),
 sourceFour.pipe(delay(3000))
);

const data = example.pipe(
       tap((val) => array.push(val)),
       switchMap(() => of(array))
       );
const subscribe = data.pipe(last()).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
//output: ["Hello", "World!", "World!"]
```

here is the working solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-u4swov?file=index.ts